# Diagrams for critical points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory, critical-point-theory

In *Hatcher, Allen; Lochak, Pierre; Schneps, Leila*, [**On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2000.028), J. Reine Angew. Math. 521, 1-24 (2000). [ZBL0953.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0953.20030)) pages 13 and 15 we have :

for case "d" and "e"we have following diagram (shapes right) :

[image]

> why these are diagrams for "d" and "e" ? i can't understand how we can get this diagram ?

i think we have following relation and shape for "d" and "e":

[image]

> are my pictures true ? how we can get  diagrams for "d" and  "e" ?

Comment: You need to supply more information if you want a response.  i.e. I don't think many readers will download a paper to find your example.

Comment: @RyanBudney .There are **sixteen** possible configurations
of three saddles on one level, shown in figure 10 of paper, where the saddles are regarded as
1-handles, or rectangles, attached to level curves. The sixteen configurations are grouped
into eight pairs, the two configurations in each pair being related by replacing $f_{tu}$ by its
negative.
$$
f_{t u}(x, y)=\pm x^{4} \pm\left(u-u_{0}\right) x^{2} \pm\left(t-t_{0}\right) x \pm y^{2}
$$